# How to mix Qt, C++ and Obj-C/Cocoa

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, qt, qmake

I have a pure C++/Qt project on a Mac, but I now find that I need to call a few methods only available in the Cocoa API. Following instructions listed here:

http://el-tramo.be/blog/mixing-cocoa-and-qt

I have a C++ class implementation in a ".m" file. As a test, my "foo.m" file contains the following code (relevant `#include` methods have been stripped for clarity).:

```
int foo::getMagicNumber()
{
    NSCursor *cursor = [NSCursor new];
}
```

Apparently, I need to add the .m file to a qmake variable called `OBJECTIVE_SOURCES`. My project .pro file looks like this:

```
TARGET = testApp
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
OBJECTIVE_SOURCES += foo.m
HEADERS += test.h
```

However, I get the following error whenever I try and compile my project:

`foo.h:4expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'foo'`

This is pointing at the `class foo` file in my header file. If I remove all cocoa calls from the .m file, and move the .m file into the `SOURCES` section of my Qt .pro file everything works as expected.

I'm using Qt 4.6.0.

My question is: What is the recommended way of integrating Cocoa calls with Qt / C++, and what am i doing wrong in the example above?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's compiling your `.m` file as Objective-C. You want it to be a `.mm` file for Objective-C++.

Comment: Doh! problem was that the ".m" file should actually be ".mm" - once that has been changed then everything works perfectly.