# Programming with Qt creator and Cocoa ( copying the selected text from the current application)

Tags: c++, cocoa, qt

I would like to know if there is a way to use the Cocoa API in a Qt application.

I've already used the Windows API to get the selected text from the active application.
I'd like to do the same with mac os.
I tried to make a simple "hello world" application C++ with xCode, including the `<Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` but it didn't work as I excepted.
Is there a way to get this "hello word" application to build with Cocoa?

And, also If that is possible, can I get the selected text from the active windows with Cocoa API?

**EDIT :**

All right, so I successfully build something using Cocoa.h, thanks to this thread : [How to mix Qt, C++ and Obj-C/Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355056/how-to-mix-qt-c-and-obj-c-cocoa).

For the selection problem you could check out the answers I posted which tell you how to do it.

Comment: I'm using Qt with Cocoa without any problem. Just create Qt application and add obj-c files to your project

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I tried #include <Cocoa/cocoa.h> and mac: LIBS += -framework Cocoa in the .pro file. But I get 9689 errors to be exact... And I'm puzzled, when I run an empthy Qt app, it open an x11 frame, is that normal ? I thought Mac OS didn't use x11 anymore.

Comment: You must use Objective-C++ if you want to use C++ with Cocoa. Your implementation files must use the `.mm` file extension. I know very little about Qt so I can't help with that.

Comment: Qt doesn't use X11 under OS X, unless one configures it at compile time to do so. Which I've only seen in the combination of macports and KDE 3, years ago.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to mix Qt, C++ and Obj-C/Cocoa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355056/how-to-mix-qt-c-and-obj-c-cocoa)

Comment: You must keep your objc code in separate .mm file

Comment: Take a look how does Qt do it http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/trees/4.8/src/gui/util

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who could be interested : I found a way to get the current selected text.

Just by simulating <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> :

So thanks to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379867/simulating-key-press-events-in-mac-os-x), I changed the code to obtain the "c" key which is represented by the integer 8 (Found in NSEvent.h), so here's the code :

```
CGEventSourceRef source = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState);
CGEventRef saveCommandDown = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, (CGKeyCode)8, YES);
CGEventSetFlags(saveCommandDown, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand);
CGEventRef saveCommandUp = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, (CGKeyCode)8, NO);

CGEventPost(kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap, saveCommandDown);
CGEventPost(kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap, saveCommandUp);

CFRelease(saveCommandUp);
CFRelease(saveCommandDown);
CFRelease(source);
```

Now you just have to access the clipboard from Qt to get the selection. (If ask, I can put the  code to do so)

Anyway, thanks to the stackoverflow community ;)