# Sending a message to Mountain Lion notification centre with Core foundation

Tags: c++, macos, qt, notifications, core-foundation

I'm developing a daemon with Qt and am wanting to send messages to the Mountain Lion notification centre: -

[image]

Qt seems to lack support for this, which isn't surprising as it's not cross-platform.

If I were using Cocoa, it looks like I would use the NSUserNotificationCenter class with an NSUserNotification.

Up until now, whenever I've seen a *Foundation class*, there has always been a matching *Core Foundation* class, but it appears that there is no CFUserNotificationCenter, but there is a CFUserNotification.

So, am I right that NSNotificationCenter is what Cocoa uses for this and is it possible to send messages to the Notification Centre without Cocoa?

If it is possible, please can someone post a code example in C or C++, or at least point out which functions to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily [integrate Qt/C++ code with Cocoa/Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355056/how-to-mix-qt-c-and-obj-c-cocoa). XCode supports Objective-C++ which is a mix of C++ and Objective-C. These files will have a **.mm** extension and are added to your QMake project using the `OBJECTIVE_SOURCES` variable (which is unfortunately not in the official QMake documentation). So just add the `NSUserNotification` code right into a C++ class.

**QMake Project File**

```
HEADERS += Foo.h
OBJECTIVE_SOURCES += Foo.mm
LIBS += -framework Foundation
INCLUDEPATH += /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Headers
```

**Foo.h**

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H
class Foo {
public:
  void test();
};

#endif
```

**Foo.mm**

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <NSUserNotification.h>

void Foo::test() {
  NSUserNotification *userNotification = [[[NSUserNotification alloc] init] autorelease];
  userNotification.title = @"My Great Title";
  userNotification.informativeText = @"Blah Blah Blah";

  [[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] deliverNotification:userNotification];
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy. I thought that mixing Objective C with Qt was only going to be simple from XCode, but Qt Creator handles it just as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No need for native code. `QSystemTrayIcon::showMessage()` is working as expected for me in 10.9.5 (Qt 5.3.2).

```
QSystemTrayIcon tray_icon;
auto menu = new QMenu;
tray_icon.setContextMenu(menu);
tray_icon.show();
tray_icon.showMessage("Test message", "Test body");
```

[image]

Comment: sorry it's not the same. The question concerns posting messages to the Notification Centre, which can be done from any application, not just those with a System Tray icon. These messages are different.

Comment: I don't understand the distinction. These messages appear in the Notification Center for me, just like those from any other app.

Comment: they may appear in the Notification Center, but your code requires a QSystemTrayIcon, so only works with that present.

Comment: The icon itself need not be present - simply remove the call to `QSystemTrayIcon::show()`. Or are you saying that because you are developing a daemon, you do not want to include `QtGui`?

Comment: No, a daemon is irrelevant as it can't display UI. Creating a QSystemTrayIcon in this instance, just to display the message and not use the system tray icon is a bit overkill. In addition, you can't set the calling application's icon using this method, so it's not ideal. However, you're right in that it could be used for basic messages.

Comment: Did you have Growl installed? `QSystemTrayIcon::showMessage()` required Growl to be installed on the system. Otherwise it simply doesn't work.